# Jersey ResourceConfig.register

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

I was wondering if there were any differences between these two syntax while registering a class in a Config.java:

```
register(MainBinder.class);
```

and

```
register(new MainBinder());
```

Is there a good practice?

Comment: What is that? An `AbstractBinder`? If so, the first will not work. If it's a general question about resource classes, one is a singleton and one is per request. I haven't seen any definitive arguments that would lead me to believe one is "better practice" over the other. Personally I prefer the per request.

Comment: Hello, nope it's not an abstract binder. I was asking this question because I found these two types of registering in the code of the company where I do my internship. And they didn't manage to answer me clearly.. So the MainBinder.class is a singleton and new MainBinder is per request? thx for your precisions

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there are any difference, but, if the class you want to register requires some init OR does not have a no-args constructor, passing the instance makes sense.